# Changing the name od a dropdown using javascript onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, onchange

Hi I need to change the name of a dropdown box depending on what is selected from the list.

```
<form  name="dofilter" method="post" action="<%=site_url%>/product">
    <select name="ff" onchange="form.submit();">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="brut">brut</option>
        <option value="Moet"> Moet</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

If the option brut is selected I need the select name to be FK 
and 
If the option Moet is selected i need the select name to be FF

Help Please

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need this? Changing the name of a form element is very odd, considering the back-end processing code that receives the information relies on the names being static so that it can read that values. Why not kep the name as something generic, eg. `Type` and then change the value of the `option` elements to `FK` and `FF` respectively?

Comment: yes, the drop down box filters the products on the page by brand, i would like to add another filter to the page but with out another drop down. and the way it works the name needs to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
$("form > select").change(function () {
    $(this).parent().attr("name", $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id"));
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/s5vmqeg9/1/)

You can check by inspecting element to see the name change instantly.

Comment: Ok the options are added from a database so is there any why of caning it from option id's

Comment: <option id="filer-one" value="brut">brut</option>
               <option id="filer-two"  value="Moet"> Moet</option>

Comment: yes, I will edit the answer and link to the new JSFiddle .

Comment: Does each of the option has an _id_ which contains the value to be set as the form's name?

Comment: Hi, Yes they have the values to be set in them.

Comment: Hi Ahs, What is the console?

Comment: The section in _Inspect Element_ that shows you any javascript errors that showed up when the code was executed.

Comment: no it is not showing any errors. how dues this script know witch drop down box it is looking at?